# Brezis-Nirenberg result compared to abstract bifurcation theory 

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

Dear Mathoverflow'ers,

I am interested in the following equation:

$-\Delta u = u^{p-1} + \lambda u$ in $ \Omega$  with $ u=0 $ on $ \partial \Omega$.

1) My question is related to the Brezis-Nirenberg result from 1983 which states (and I am probably slightly off here)  that  when $ p=2^*$ (the critical Sobolev exponent)  that there is a positive solution for certain values of $ \lambda$ and they can give an optimal range of $ \lambda$ (in certain cases) where one has a positive solution.

2) I believe that at the time it was very suprising that the addition of this linear term could restore compactness in the critical imbedding and recover a positive solution.

3) In another direction one can use some abstract bifurcation theory (i believe it would be the results of Crandall-Rabinowitz from the mid seventies)  to show there is a positive solution  for any value of $ p>2$  (as large as one likes) provided  $ \lambda$ was sufficiently close (and to the left) of   the first eigenvalue of $ -\Delta$.

My question is that since 3) was already well known why was 1) so suprising?
I realize that this is somewhat of an ill formed question and may not be suitable for mathoverflow.

thanks
Greg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several reasons why  the work of Brezis-Nirenberg was surprising.

1. First,  it goes beyond a small range of $\lambda$'s that one would obtain from bifurcation theory.
2. The existence of positive solutions  is highly dependent  on the geometry and  topology of $\Omega$.

Comment: Hi Liviu,  

  I kinda suspected that 1 was the reason but wasn't quite sure. Thanks for the quick responce.     